# Series Convergence

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose I have a series $\sum a_n$ that is absolutely convergent. How to show that  $\sum a^2_n$ is convergent? I can imagine this to be true, but I'm not sure how to prove it mathematically.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hint: Eventually, $|a_n|<1$, and then $0\le a_n^2\le|a_n|$. Use a comparison   test.